# Best way to store program state variables in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm writing an app in C# that connects to a SQL Server using Entity Framework. Every instance of the app shares the tables and some variables (ints, strings and bools).

What's the best way to share that variables (int string and bools) via tables in SQL Server?

Since tables have fixed type columns, one table would not do it without loosing type-safe in C#, because every type should be converted to string or boxed to object.

The two solutions I came up with are, one table with 3 columns (`int`, `varchar`, `bool`), with the data writing in the appropriately typed column, or 3 tables with one column.

Or maybe I am totally missing the point here..

The question would be: what's the most elegant way to accomplish saving typed data to a SQL Server?

Comment: And in which column would you store `float`?  or `decimal`? or `DateTime`?

Comment: You could store the information in a single column, in an xml or json string. That way you don't have to worry about the datatype of your column. You then handle the desrialization in your code to use the right datatype to store each value.

Comment: `one table would not do it without loosing type-safe in C#,` why? Why use *one* table and why lose type safety? Different attributes should be stored in different fields, so there's no reason to lose type safety.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use store different attributes on the same fields. That's a very bad idea, in fact it's the reason SharePoint queries are so excruciatingly slow. Different entities should be mapped to different tables. If you don't need to query individual entities/attributes, you can use XML or JSON data. Or you can add *all possible* attributes as [sparse table columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-sparse-columns?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SQL_Variant` for that purpose

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/sql-variant-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

```
CREATE   TABLE tableA(colA sql_variant, colB int)  
INSERT INTO tableA values ( cast (46279.1 as decimal(8,2)), 1689)  
SELECT   SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(colA,'BaseType') AS 'Base Type',  
         SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(colA,'Precision') AS 'Precision',  
         SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(colA,'Scale') AS 'Scale'  
FROM      tableA  
WHERE      colB = 1689
```